# Time analysis for subsets of size k

Tags: combinations

```
public static List < List < Integer >> combinations(int n, int k) {
    List < List < Integer >> result = new ArrayListof);
    directedCombinations(n, k, 1, new ArrayList < Integer > (), result);
    return result;
}
private static void directedCombinations(int n, int k, int offset,
    291 List < Integer > partialCombination,
    ListcList < Integer >> result) {
    if (partialCombination.size() == k) {
        result.add(new ArrayList < > (partialCombination));
        return;
    }
    // Generate remaining combinations over {offset , ...» n - 1} of size
    // numRemaining.
    final int numRemaining = k - partialCombination.size();
    for (int i = offset; i <= n && numRemaining <= n - i + 1; ++i) {
        partialCombination.add(i);
        directedCombinations(n, k, i + 1, partialCombination, result);
        partialCombination.remove(partialCombination.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

What is the time analysis for this solution, my book says it is O(n * nCk)? nCk makes sense, but dont get why it is n * nCk. Appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this line:

```
result.add(new ArrayList < > (partialCombination));
```

You've generated `C(n,k)` solutions. Now for each of them you perform array creation. This takes time proportional to its size, namely `O(k)`. So it would be more precise to say that the time is `O(k * C(n,k))`.

So, if you didn't have to output the array, but return, say, `1` or the sum of the numbers in the array, you can make the algorithm run in `O(C(n,k))`.